# Multiple scoped Styles in QuickJS

Tags: javascript, qwik, qwikjs

I tried to use two style sheets for my header component, one for the layout and the other is for the color scheme. I tried all means of concatenation but still giving me error. I can combine two css files into one but that is not in my plan yet.

```js
import style1 from './header.dark.css?inline'
import style2 from './header.css?inline'
...
let stylex= style2.concat(style1)
useStylesScoped$(stylex);
```

the error

[plugin:vite-plugin-qwik]
Qrl($) scope is not a function, but it's capturing local identifiers: stylex

Comment: turns out you dont need to merge the styles, just  call useStylesScoped$ for each style is good enough.